# How to not prompt during FormFlow on BotBuilder?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to design a FormFlow where one of the fields is a free text that is quite hard to process. The user is prompted to describe one item, but:

- the description must be at least 200 words long
- the description **should not be required to be sent as a single message**

So I made a string field, prompted the user for the description. If the the description is too short I prompt again for more text using a `FieldReflector` with `.SetActive` based on the previous field.

The problem is that I don't know how to make this silently (I'd rather warn the minimum amount of words only in the first time and just keep grabbing content until it satisfies the length requirement).

I also tried to use `validate`, modifying aggregating the inputs somewhere else at every validate check. But this way the bot also has to say (apparently) some feedback before the next try.

I'll have to design a clever way to stop filling this field, probably detecting the intent to stop with LUIS, but the goal for now is to make this field easy to fill with multiple messages and no interruptions.